# How to insert a LinkedListNode into a LinkedList based on comparison criteria?

Tags: c#, .net, linked-list

I have written a C# program that makes used of a LinkedList-based object:

[.NET LinkedList class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)

I would like to keep this LinkedList in sequential order (low to high) based on one of the member's contained within the LinkedList's nodes.  I can think about how to do this the "long" way, namely checking to see if the list is empty prior to adding the new node, and then loop through the list until I find the one node that is greater than the one to be added and then add the new member, but I would like to see if there is a clever shorthand way to do this in .NET.

Does .NET have some way to accomplish what I want to do?  I thought about using [SkipWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075.aspx), but how would I put this in a loop that also handles an empty list and the point where I reach the end of a list and add the item at the end?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using LinkedList? If not there is SortedList.

Comment: @Aron My project began prior to the need for sorting.  I'll see if SortedList works out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No.   If you want stuff sorted, you should use a sortable collection:

Here's one (there are others):   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx